# Edit HTML where anonymous function is placed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the HTML contents of wherever this script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/request/something",
            data: {
                // ...
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // ...
                var html = "...";
                $(this).parent().html(html);
                }
            }
        })
    })();
</script>
```

I placed this script into an existing `div` element, but the execution of this script won't change the HTML of that `div` element.

Comment: because `this` will not refer the div you want

Comment: Not sure you are understanding how this works. You'll need to select your element before trying to modify it or it's contents.

Comment: you should be able to set an `id` to your `script` tag to select it and get its parent (but if you can, better even to set the id to the div itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `this`, use an argument that will be set to `document.currentScript.parentNode`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <script>
    (function (elem) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
            data: {
                // ...
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // ...
                var html = "display this";
                $(elem).html(html);
            }
        })
    })(document.currentScript.parentNode); // pass this value
    </script>
</div>
```

Do realise that this is not the way it is commonly done. Consider giving your element some `id` or `class` and reference that in a script that you position at the end of the document:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
    data: {
        // ...
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // ...
        var html = "display this";
        $("#target").html(html);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: smart answer it is

Answer (score 1):

the keyword `this` refers to the scope of the success function in your ajax request. You should set the `id` attribute of the div you want to change.

Then you can change it's innerHTML much easyer.

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/request/something",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myDiv').innerHTML = data.responseText;
//              ^^^^^ use the id of the div you want to change
            }
        }
    })
});
```

I hope this can help somehow.